# Collapsing identical adjacent rows in a Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas

Basically if a column of my pandas dataframe looks like this:

```
[1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 1 1]
```

I'd like it to be turned into the following:

```
[1 2 3 1]
```

Comment: Does the order matter? Are you working with a DataFrame or a Series?

Answer (score 1):

#### You can write a simple function that loops through the elements of your series only storing the first element in a run.

As far as I know, there is no tool built in to pandas to do this. But it is not a lot of code to do it yourself.

```
import pandas
example_series = pandas.Series([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3])

def collapse(series):
    last = ""
    seen = []
    for element in series:
        if element != last:
            last = element
            seen.append(element)
    return seen
        
collapse(example_series)
```

In the code above, you will iterate through each element of a series and check if it is the same as the last element seen. If it is not, store it. If it is, ignore the value.

If you need to handle the return value as a series you can change the last line of the function to:

```
return pandas.Series(seen)
```

Comment: I don't want the unique elements. See revised example above. And Assume a Dataframe with one column.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function that does the following:

```
x = pandas.Series([1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 1 1])
y = x-x.shift(1)
y[0] = 1
result = x[y!=0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use DataFrame's diff and indexing:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,1])
>>> df[df[0].diff()!=0]
    0
0   1
2   2
6   3
10  1
>>> df[df[0].diff()!=0].values.ravel() # If you need an array
array([1, 2, 3, 1])
```

Same works for Series:

```
>>> df = pd.Series([1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,1])
>>> df[df.diff()!=0].values
array([1, 2, 3, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shift` to create a boolean mask to compare the row against the previous row:

```
In [67]:
s = pd.Series([1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,5])
s[s!=s.shift()]

Out[67]:
0     1
2     2
6     3
10    4
12    5
dtype: int64
```